# Functions in a React Native Component (function vs const function)

Tags: reactjs, function, react-native, function-declaration

This is probably super simple but I can't quite word how to search for an answer.

I've just noticed I have functions in my react native components that sometimes I declare with const while others I don't and there seems to be no difference.

Like so

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
 
     const myFunction = () => {
        console.log("Hello world");
     }
     return(
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={myFunction}>
            ...somestuff
         </TouchableOpacity>
     )
}
```

or

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
 
     myFunction = () => {
        console.log("Hello world");
     }
     return(
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={myFunction}>
            ...somestuff
         </TouchableOpacity>
     )
}
```

I can't find anything different between them in terms of output. Is this just the compiler saving my a*s or is there actually a difference between them?

Comment: Since I don't actually know I'll leave this as a comment, but my guess is that the compiler is saving you - and I say this because my linter complains if I don't use const/let on a function like that.

Comment: Agreed, the second is definitely not correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript won't stop you from using undeclared variables.

`x = 10; // This is completely fine, as it'll be added in global scope`

To avoid doing this, generally `use strict` is used.

```
"use strict";
x = 10;       // This will cause an error because x is not declared
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think in react native it matters because of it's lifecycles. But in normal javascript it has a difference in hoisting. Without const you can call a function that hasn't been declared:

```
doTheThing();


function doTheThing() {
   console.log(`This is awesome number ${getAwesome()}`)
}

function getAwesome() {
  return (+((Math.random() * 10000).toString().split('.')[0]))
}
```

With Const/let it doens't let you do that:

```
 const tryDoTheThing = () => {
    console.log(`This is me trying to be awesome ${getAwesome()}`)
 }


 // "getAwesome is not defined", because it is referenced too early
 tryDoTheThing() // comment to see the rest work


 const getAwesome = () => (+((Math.random() * 10000).toString().split('.')[0]))


 const doTheThing = () => {
   console.log(`This is awesome! ${getAwesome()}`)
 }

 doTheThing() // prints
```

using `function` will put it's declaration on top of the current scope (to the top of the current script or the current function).